# What weapon do I need to break into a Manufacturing Facility?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've just come across a Manufacturing Facility on my planet and am trying to open the door, but with little success.

Unlike the locked doors in Space Stations and Outposts which ask for an Atlas Pass, these just state the door is reinforced.

My mining laser doesn't seem to do anything to it, but also didn't attract the sentinel droids that were around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To open these kind of reinforced doors you must either install a boltcaster on your Multitool or Plasma Grenades. This will attract the sentinel droids though when destroying the door. Personally I recommend the Grenades, because they can destroy the doors much faster than the Boltcaster. :-)

Comment: You recommend grenades because [fill in the blank by [edit]ing the answer]?

Comment: Is the recommendation because I'll only need one grenade, or just a few which will be quicker? Or because they'll bounce off and hit me instead? ;)

Comment: You need about eight grenades to open a secure door.  If you count to three between grenades, you can avoid angering the sentinels too.

Comment: @ Zhaph hahaha, edited the answer to make it more clear why I prefer it

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Grenades blast open the door faster in the early game when you don't have boltcaster damage-ups yet. However, once you have enough damage and shot speed, the boltcaster is more effective (assuming you don't upgrade the grenades).

Comment: If you have the health to survive a minor assault you can do whatever you want to the door. The sentinels stop attacking as soon as you get inside.

Comment: @MageXy These things I know. :) That's why the answer should explain—because it's not actually always better.

Comment: You forgot punching, you can punch the door open. It takes a while but works. Handy at the start of the game.

Comment: As I only use grenades to dig holes, they are always super weak so would take me a long while to open a door.  My boltcaster with an omega and sigma damage upgrade takes 45 shots, and with a clip upgrade I don't have to reload. I can usually destroy the door before any sentinel gets close enough to shoot at me.

Answer (score 2):

With a lower powered multi-tool you will need to use a bolt caster or preferably grenades to open these doors.

A mining laser with few or no mods can't get in but I find that my fully upgraded mining laser has no problems.

Comment: I couldn't open doors with my mining laser until I installed the railgun mod for it, don't know if there are other mods that will do the same, but might be worth adding to the answer as hitting the door with a standard laser didn't do squat for me before that, even with lots of other upgrades :)

Comment: I built the railgun mod last so I don't think that's exactly it. I do recall with no mods the mining laser does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your starship's photon cannons work, as long as if you're in an outdoor area.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/258869)

Comment: @MBraedley I think it does add a new answer to the question, I've suggested an edit that might help make it more of an answer.

Answer (score -3):

You need the boltcaster or plasma grenade upgrade equipped on your multi-tool in order to blow up the doors to get into these facility's.